# Can't find field when using symbol reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, webrat

I'm playing around with RoR for the first time and hit a weird error. I have the following test code for my navigation links:

```
describe "when logged in" do 
  before(:each) do
    @user = Factory(:user)
    visit login_path

    #the line below is the weird one
    fill_in "session[user_name]", :with => @user.user_name

    fill_in :password, :with => @user.password
    click_button
  end

  it "should have navigation links" do
    response.should have_selector("nav")
  end

  it "should have link to log out" do
    response.should have_selector("a", :href => logout_path, :content => "Log out")      
  end  
end
```

the code above works just fine, but if I would change the line

```
fill_in "session[user_name]", :with => @user.user_name
```

to

```
fill_in :user_name, :with => @user.user_name
```

it won't work and I can't figure out why. The error I get is

```
Failure/Error: fill_in :user_name, :with => @user.user_name
   Webrat::NotFoundError:
   Could not find field: :user_name
```

The relevant generated html is:

```
<label for="session_user_name">User name</label><br/>
<input id="session_user_name" name="session[user_name]" size="30" type="text" />
<label for="session_password">Password</label><br/>
<input id="session_password" name="session[password]" size="30" type="password" />
```

If you look at the code you see I do exactly that for the password, and that works just fine. I would like to use the syntax which is causing the error so am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please include the output HTML for your form.

Comment: see update... only added the relevant part of the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
fill_in "user name", :with => @user.user_name
```

I think webrat is being nice, and its able to find your label 'Password' because it is case insensitive and its turning `:password` into 'Password'.

You could also use the HTML `id` attribute, i.e.

```
fill_in :session_user_name, :with => @user.user_name
```

One gotcha here is if you are thinking of switching to use Capybara rather than Webrat: Capybara is case-sensitive, so it would fail on `fill_in "user name"`.

I'm not sure what the best practice is here, but I have switched to using the HTML `id` and `name` attributes rather than the label text in my own code.  The reason for this is that it is less brittle because people change the customer-facing text on the site more than they change the semantic elements and names.